# xchat Connection failed. Error: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: irc

Idk the problem if anyone of you can help me then I'll be thankful to you.

As I do regularly I open my xchat (irc client) and then when I select **frrenode** to connect then I am getting this crappy error.
I try to connect with other irc to and I got same error.
I just checked my network setting on irc and everything is fine over there idk wtf is going on .

Error shown below

```
Quote: * Looking up irc.freenode.net
* Connecting to irc.freenode.net (213.232.93.3) port 6667...
* Connection failed. Error: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```