# Xchat on Freenode - strange behaviour

Tags: authentication, connection, xchat2

I looked this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270606/xchat-connection-failed-error-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way) on XChat, but it doesn't solved my issue.

I am trying to use Xchat on freenode:

```
/msg NickServ IDENTIFY <password>
You have not registered
Closing Link: 999.999.999.999 (Connection timed out)
#22*# Disconnected (Remote host closed socket).
 Cycling to next server in Ubuntu Servers...
#22*# Disconnected ().
```

Then I did the command to check my nickname:

```
/whois <mynickname>
* Disconnected ().
* Looking up irc.freenode.net
* Connecting to chat.freenode.net (99.999.99.999) port 8001...
* Connected. Now logging in...
* *** Looking up your hostname...
* *** Checking Ident
* *** Couldn't look up your hostname
* *** No Ident response
* <mynickname> already in use. Retrying with <mynickname>..
```

Then I typed the command to request my password, but received no message in my mail-box:

```
/msg NickServ SENDPASS <mynickname>
#22*# *** Looking up your hostname...
#22*# *** Checking Ident
#22*# *** Couldn't look up your hostname
#22*# *** No Ident response
#22*# <mynickname> already in use. Retrying with <mynickname>...
#22*# <mynickname> already in use. Retrying with <mynickname>...
#22*# Nickname already in use. Use /NICK to try another.
```

The Xchat Freenode keeps giving the message all the time:

```
* *** Looking up your hostname...
* Disconnected (Connection reset by peer).
 Cycling to next server in FreeNode...
* Disconnected ().
* Looking up irc.freenode.netnot woYou are not authorized to perform this operationrking
* Connecting to chat.freenode.net (999.999.999.999) port 8001...
* Connected. Now logging in...
* *** Looking up your hostname...
* *** Checking Ident
* *** Couldn't look up your hostname
```

The funny thing is, whenever I try to login using the web-browser through the [link](http://webchat.freenode.net), then it works nicely. Even, if I first login in any channel through the web-browser, and then I go on XChat and try to login in some other channel after doing it first on browser, then after that XChat works without problem.

Now, if I try the command:

```
/whois <mynickname>
* [<mynickname>] (~<mynickname>@99.999.9.999): Linda Lowela
* [<mynickname>] #webkit 
* [<mynickname>] dickson.freenode.net :US
* [<mynickname>] is connecting from *@99.999.9.999  99.999.9.999
* [<mynickname>] idle 00:00:51, signon: Wed Jan  1 21:12:31
* [<mynickname>] End of WHOIS list.
```

So, what is happening here and why this strange behaviour on XChat?

Please any advise are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open your XChat, try instead simply to do following steps:

1. Select your channel: Freenode
2. Have a look in this short and friendly [tutorial](http://kmacphail.blogspot.ca/2011/09/using-weechat-with-freenode-basics.html)
3. From the command prompt if you are on Freenode, your  should appears in the command field. Something like: {nickname}|
4. Enter the command from the XChat prompt, have it selected on Freenode - {nickname}| : {prompt to enter the command}

   /join #{channel-name}

It should work. Besides, have a look in this reference material: [The Book of IRC](http://www.amazon.ca/The-Book-IRC-Ultimate-Internet/dp/1886411298).